# PHP Bug day of year

Tags: php, date, datetime

I'm trying to convert day of year into date.

So no problem i use DateTime::createFromFormat with z and Y.

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y', '199 2020');

/*RESULT*/
object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2020-07-19 12:45:24.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
```

But when i test the result i get the wrong day of year...

```
date('z Y', strtotime('2020-07-19'));

/*RESULT*/
'198 2020' (length=8)
```

So i trying this

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('z Y', date('z Y', strtotime('2020-07-19')));

/*RESULT*/
object(DateTime)[3]
  public 'date' => string '2020-07-20 12:52:10.000000' (length=26)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
```

if i check day of year 199 of 2020 on this website: https://www.calendrier.best/numero-de-jour-2020.html

I get 2020-07-17

What i'm doing wrong ??

Comment: the problem looks to be with timezone settings , set a timezone globally and then check

Comment: Just for clarification: z starts with 0. So '0 2020' should be 2020-01-01

Comment: My timezone is setted globally

Comment: This is a Bug in PHP. The problem seems to be with leap year 2020. The correct result is returned for January and February; from March 2020 it is incorrect. For 2019 all results are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the year, you can use something like this. Outputs:

```
string(10) "2020-07-17"
```

Code:

```
<?php

$dayOfYearNumber = 199;
$year = 2020;

// Add day of year number to the first day of the year, substracting 1 because Jan 1st will be the first day.
$date = (new DateTime("$year-1-1"))->add(new DateInterval('P' . $dayOfYearNumber - 1 . 'D'));

var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d')); // string(10) "2020-07-17"
```

Comment: An alternative would be `->modify('+'.($dayOfYearNumber - 1).' days')`.

Answer (score 0):

PHP only detects some standards like you can see here https://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.date.php

In Your first example you defined your format but `strtotime()` has no such parameter

If you have these values as variable you could use `mktime()` instead https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mktime

But I recommend to always give PHP a month e.x. January

Comment: OP is not using the format as a parameter to `strtotime` anywhere in the code. And how do you propose that `mktime` creates something from the value of `199`?